# why opendir() function cannot accept php variables as $dir=opendir("upload/$userid/post/$postid");

Tags: php

> 43 2 upload/2 /post/43 
>   Warning: opendir(upload/2 /post/43 ,upload/2 /post/43 ): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\php\displaypostbox.php on line 23
>
> Warning: opendir(upload/2 /post/43 ): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\php\displaypostbox.php on line 23
>
> Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\php\displaypostbox.php on line 24

Comment: And your code is where?

Comment: looks like you have to trim your values ?

Comment: thanks Random bro Its works (trim())

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$a_dir="upload/$userid/post/$postid";
if(file_exists($a_dir)){
   $dir=opendir($a_dir);
}
```